# Handling dynamic json from client in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

<strike>I am developing a node js project in which the end-user can create and update outlets in mongoDb database. Now, let's say there are hundreds of fields in the outlet schema but the user may not update each and every field, i.e one may update 2 fields, other may update 3 fields. So, I want to create a function that can handle each type of request. I don't know this can be done or there is some other way, but i am new to this, can you suggest me something suitable for my project. Thanks in advance!</strike>

Sorry for the confusion earlier.

I am developing a project in nodejs for retail outlets. Each outlet has over 50 fields in the database while registering. Registration is fine. The POST request via API specifies all the data required.

But when I am planning to update any of those field. I am not sure what approach to handle. Sometimes only 1 field will be changed or next time a bunch of them with no order/sequence.
Example :

```
{"id":"ABCD", "name":"MNOPQR"}
{"id":"ABCD", "time":123, "name":"ZYX"}
```

So here in first query I need to only update the name while in next I need to update both name and time.
Is there any way I can manage the dynamic json parsing at server end and updating only those fields (int database) that are mentioned in the request.

Comment: I think it would be quite beneficial if you read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I will make sure that next time while posting a question, but for now, can you help me for my query, if you know it then! @ZombieChowder

Answer (score 0):

You have several approaches you can use.

One is to accept an object with the changes:

```
function doTheChanges(changes) {
    Object.keys(changes).forEach(name => {
        const value = changes[name];
        // Use `name` (the field name) and `value` (the value) to do the update
    });
}
```

Called like this:

```
doTheChanges({foo: "bar", biz: "baz"});
```

...to change the `foo` field to `"bar"` and the `biz` field to `"baz"`. (Names that have invalid identifier chars, etc., can be put in double quotse: `{"I'm an interesting field name": "bar"}`.)

Alternately you could accept an array of changes with `name` and `value` prperties:

```
function doTheChanges(changes) {
    changes.forEach(({name, value}) => {
        // Use `name` (the field name) and `value` (the value) to do the update
    });
}
```

Called like this:

```
doTheChanges([
    {
        name: "foo",
        value: "bar"
    },
    {
        name: "biz",
        value: "baz"
    }
]);
```

You could also just accept a varying number of parameters, where each parameter is an object with `name` and `value` properties:

```
function doTheChanges(...changes) {
    changes.forEach(({name, value}) => {
        // Use `name` (the field name) and `value` (the value) to do the update
    });
}
```

Called like this:

```
doTheChanges(
    {
        name: "foo",
        value: "bar"
    },
    {
        name: "biz",
        value: "baz"
    }
);
```

Note that that's very similar to the array option.

Or use the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), but it's probably overkill here.

Comment: You're saying that, i have to pass array of changes to the function, but i can update the fields using postman for now. So, do you have anything in mind, that can help me!

Comment: @VikasValechha: I have no idea what you're asking there.

Comment: I am asking that, for now the project is in development and to test the application, i am using postman for my GET and POST queries, so, what you told over there to pass the object, that is not possible with postman as in my code, i am using "var name = req.body.name" to get the response from the server.

Comment: @VikasValechha: With respect, your question had nothing to do with postman. You asked how to create a function that could support updating a wide variety of fields. I answered the question you asked. If you have further questions, after (of course) doing thorough research, [searching ghere on SO](/help/searching), and trying to do the work, you could post another question specifically asking about the thing where you're stuck (showing what you've done, etc.).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's why answering the question in the first place wasn't the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @ZombieChowder: Well, I disagree. There was a clear question there -- not well-presented, but clear enough if you read closely. It's only in the comments that it went completely pear-shaped.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `put` request you can use `patch` request so that only the values you change get affected in database .